# Javascript multithread both window focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, firefox, focus

I want to focus two windows tabs(browsers) at the same time. How to I make it using javascript ? or there is an alternative way doing this from firefox add-ons.

Comment: What do you mean by focussing two browser tabs together?

Answer (score 0):

The focus can only be on one window at a time, this is because there is only one window you will ultimately be able to focus on.

Therefore it is quite useless to focus 2 windows at the same time.

It is however possible to fill in multiple fields of a form at the same time for instance.